# How to get most interacted friends for a FB user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get the most interacted friends(like top 10 friends) of a FB user??
I tried to look for any available Graph api, but I couldn't find one.

If there is no such api, does anyone know any alternate ways to get atleast the recently interacted users?

Interaction may be such a like, share, comment or new friend request accepted..

Answer (score 1):

You can get home feed with recent X feed and group by friend id. Friends who has most activity count on your home feed, they will be most (and recently) interacted friends.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still I feel to find out something different, since the most recent feed doesn't mean that I've interacted with them. Consider I've a friend who used to share/post much more all throughout day , then obviously he will be only person in the recent posts but that person may not be most interacted/closest friend. The idea/reason to get most interacted/close friends is to list them and increase the possibility of social interaction in my application :)

Comment: Right, agree with Vijay on this.  We need something similar -- a way to know the top x number of friends you consider to be your closest or interact with the most.  In our application it would allow us to present a concise list of friends to our users which would be most relevant to them.  Wish there was something for this because we all know FB has this data in-house.